# Use VB.net to drop files in third-party window

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, automation, sendmessage

I am working on a VB.net program to automate a manual process.  The process involves dragging files to a third-party program that permanently archive those files.

I am able to start the third-party program and enter the requisite user and password information and successfully login to the third party application using the SENDMESSAGE API.  I had quite a difficult time reading the status bar in the third-party application, and ended up using UI Automation to get the status bar text.

I looked, but never found a VB.net implementation of SENDMESSAGE with WM_DROPFILES.  I tried to convert a version that I found in C, but never got that to work.  One of the things I struggled with there was the structure for HDROP.

Is SENDMESSAGE with WM_DROPFILES a reliable to simulate someone dragging a file to the third-party program?  Most of the Googling I did found SENDMESSAGE and WM_DROPFILES being discussed more than a decade ago.

I investigated using UI Automation, but couldn't find a solution using that, either.

I am currently looking into SHDoDragDrop in Shell32.DLL.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never did.